# Using $this when not in object context RethinkDB time object

Tags: php, rethinkdb

I'm trying to convert an object that holds a rethinkdb datetime object (provided by the [PHP-RQL library](https://github.com/danielmewes/php-rql)) but i'm getting a fatal error saying:

`Using $this when not in object context`

This is an overview of the code:

```
$day = new stdClass;

$datetime = new DateTime();
$arrival = r\time(
    $datetime->format('Y'),
    $datetime->format('m'),
    $datetime->format('d'),
    $datetime->format('H'),
    $datetime->format('i'),
    $datetime->format('s'),
    'Z'
);

$day->arrival = $arrival;

$day = object_to_array($day);
```

It is in the `object_to_array()` function I get the fatal error, its code is:

```
function object_to_array($obj) {
    $array  = array(); // noisy $array does not exist
    $arrObj = is_object($obj) ? get_object_vars($obj) : $obj;
    foreach ($arrObj as $key => $val) {
        $val = (is_array($val) || is_object($val)) ? $this->getArray($val) : $val;
        $array[$key] = $val;
    }
    return $array;
}
```

I don't remember where I got this function came from (its not mine) but its served me well in the past.

**Essentially my question is why does this `object_to_array` function fail?**

This is what the r\time function returns (an object): https://gist.github.com/fenfe1/6676924

Note: Converting just the time object to an array works fine, but passing an object containing the time fails.

Ultimately I need to end up with an array for use in another function and as other properties will be added to the `day` object it would be beneficial to keep this as an object.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? `$this->getArray($val)` $this is a reference to an object you're inside

Comment: You seem to have copy/pasted some code, and altered it somewhat without changing all the necessary bits. Replace `$this->getArray` with `object_to_array` and you'll be fine.

Comment: @Wrikken thanks, that fixed it, I did copy the function but that was how it came - I am going to understand how it works now though. I'm not sure how I should close this question etc. though

Comment: Well, Mario's answer is correctly answering your question _why_ this fails.

Comment: This is not directly related to your question, but $arrival actually contains a RethinkDB query object. You still have to send it to a RethinkDB server using $arrival->run($connection); to convert it the the actual RethinkDB time object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message

> Using $this when not in object context

already tells you the reason why the function fails. You use $this. $this is normally used inside a class as a reference to the instantiated object, but in your case you use a simple function, so there is no object context.